# About the retrieval of data in ethereum blockchain

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

Every data in the ethereum blockchain is hashed. That is in the form merkel tree.

so how the retrieval data is possible as once the data is hashed it cannot be

reversed?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Not everything is hashed in a Blockchain. Blockchain is a data structure where transactions are stored in blocks chained by cryptographic hash functions. Bitcoin uses Merkle Tree to store transactions in a  distributed manner. Ethereum is a little bit for extensive storage architecture with ability to store the global state of the blockchain along with a few other properties of the transactions. Please find the attached image to understand the Ethereum Block architecture. Ethereum stores transactions and state in Merkle Patricia Tree Structure.

[Ethereum Data Architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbzXl.png)